# What does Ctrl + Alt + F11 do and why can't I log into my account with Unity any more?

Tags: unity, users

I was just happily typing away, trying out some Android development on my Ubuntu machine. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to run the program in Eclipse.

This made the screen go blank with a white flashing cursor and it stayed like that for a while, so I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to get to a terminal I could use and remembered seeing somewhere `startx` to start the GUI again, so I tried that and had something I have also been trying commands like `unity`, `unity start` and `unity restart`, but they all seem to run, but I never get my GUI back.

The fact that it only happened to my user account is strange. If I use guest I can access the GUI, but if I try and log in to my account the screen goes black for a few seconds and then sends be back to the log in screen.

I have tried installing the Xubuntu desktop over the top of it, but it does the same thing with that desktop as well.

My knowledge of Linux is starting to get stretched at this point now.

What may have happened and how do I put it right? Maybe it's a user setting or something I could change?

Also could anyone tell me what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> does?

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu and ran the latest updates today as well.

When running `startx`, I get an error saying:

> Fatal Server error@ server is already active for display 0 if this server is no longer running, remove `/temp/.x0-lock` and start again

Another thing I have tried is using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to bring back the GUI, but that doesn't seem to help either. It always sends me back to the log in screen (which is the GUI log in screen).

Comment: You've got two separate questions here.  You should split them up.

Comment: Thanks but i've tried ctrl + alt + 7, forgot to say that.

Comment: The first, main part of this question--the part that asks about what the key combination does in general, reflects the title of the question, and *which all the answers here so far attempt to address*--is answered in [What does “Ctrl + Alt + F12” do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/277517/what-does-ctrl-alt-f12-do). We should probably close this as a duplicate question. As [Thomas W. said](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156712/what-does-ctrl-alt-f11-do-and-why-cant-i-log-into-my-account-with-unity-any/341814#comment190274_156712), your second question should be asked separately.

Answer (score 22):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> should find your GUI again.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> buttons bring up "TTYs" which are just terminal interfaces you can use without running `gnome-terminal` or another terminal program.

> **NOTE**: In more recent Ubuntu systems, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd> are the more correct keys to use - this answer was written back in 2012 with Ubuntu 12.04 and such being the current version and the answer is no longer accurate for more recent releases.

Comment: It still doesn't take me back to where i want to be, yes i go back to the GUI, but its the log in screen. When i enter my password the screen goes blank and then sends me back to the login screen again.

Comment: Did you try rebooting?  (in terminal, login with your username and passcode, then use `sudo shutdown -r now`)

Comment: I have, well i used halt first of all and i've used the reboot command but i doubt that'll make much of a difference.

Comment: I move between virtual terminals all of the time. I just used the `ctrl`+`alt`+`f11` followed by `ctrl`+`alt`+`f7` and it worked for me. There are times when I have to reenter my userid and password to get past a locked screen, but my session is still there with all my windows intact. Sometimes I'll be on the tty8 so I have to use the `f8` sequence. I have to wonder whether if your session is somehow timing out and that is why it goes missing.

Comment: I can confirm what @JohnSGruber said, I just tested earlier today going to ctrl+alt+f11, leaving it there, then going back to ctrl+alt+f7 for the GUI on a clean Ubuntu system and it was not a problem.

Comment: In 18.04+ its control, alt, and eithwr F1 and F2 to get to GUIs now.

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> sort of puts the GUI to sleep, and puts you into a virtual terminal mode, something like the old fashion ttys.

Once in this mode you can choose between 6 different tty input screens. Each acting like it is an old-fashion tty.  The different ttys can be chosen with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> up to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.  Each of these virtual ttys will require that you log in with the old fashion Unix login that you would use from an old-fashion tty.

If you login to one of these and then try to restart the X-window server it won't let you because there is already a server running.

If you are in this virtual terminal mode you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to switch between the 6 different tty-like inputs.  Each will look just the way you left it when you switched out.  You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch to the screen (not a tty) that is attached to the already running GUI.

Note there is a difference between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ and just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+.

This mode is actually very useful if you are in something using full screen mode and you need access to a backend command shell.

Comment: In KDE (Fedora 38 at least), [Ctrl+Alt+F11 freezes the GUI](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477314). This is annoying because you can press that combo by mistake while trying to hit the right shortcut in some IDE (WebStorm is supposed to show bookmarks via Ctrl+Alt+F11).