# How do I change back to my X-session (GUI) tty?

Tags: shortcut-keys, tty, gnome-screensaver

My screensaver unlock screen got frozen, and fishing around I found that I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to switch tty's and get a (text only) terminal login.

The helpful pages that mentioned this, didn't however mention how to get back to my normal ubuntu GUI session. How do I do that??

Comment: I am facing the same problem on my laptop. Traditionally Cnt+Alt+F7 should switch to X, if running, however it does not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your graphical session is usually located at either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. For me, running Ubuntu 13.04 it is <kbd>F7</kbd>.

A related, interesting read: [What does "Ctrl + Alt + F12" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277517/what-does-ctrl-alt-f12-do)

Comment: It's F7 on 12.04 as well.

Comment: Notably for me running Zorin (Ubuntu variant) within VirtualBox right-ctrl Fn does the same thing, which was a rude surprise when I tried to hit Ctrl-F2 to set a bookmark in my text editor! I'll stick with left-Ctrl I guess..