# Locked out of my account

Tags: bash

Ok, so I've been messing around with my linux installation, and I've really kind of messed up.

I changed the ~/.gnomerc to open an application, but there was a problem: after it opened that application, it didn't do anything else. The rest of the screen was black, until I closed the appication. Then it just ran normally.

"Ok," I figured, "I've seen scripts have 'exit 0' after they were done executing, so maybe I need to add that."

Well, as you can imagine, I still have the same behaviour with the application, but now, when I close the application, it logs me out of my computer. So I can no longer edit the ~/.gnomerc file to fix it.

My solution so far is to somehow log into the root user bash in order to edit the file. Is there some way to do that? Can I log into my other account via terminal in order to edit that file? Can I somehow run the computer in "Safe Mode" or something and edit the file?

Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try logging in as your normal user in text mode (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and using `nano ~/.gnomerc` to edit the file

Comment: As root just rm ~your_user/.gnomerc

Answer (score 1):

When you're at the login screen, instead of logging in, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. That will take you to a [virtual terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/277517/85695) where you can log in in text mode.

Log in as your regular user and then simply rename the offending file:

```
mv ~/.gnomerc ~/.gnomerc.bad
```

Now, hit   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (it might be <kbd>F8</kbd>) which will take you back to the login screen, log in and everything should be back to normal.