# My mouse pointer is shredded / chopped up

Tags: 14.04, ati, mouse, radeon, cursor

Yesterday my mouse cursor got into a fight with a terminal cursor and lost. No not really, but suddenly it changed to being chopped up so that parts of it are shifted.  It still works, but its distracting to look at and I'm wondering if there is a way to fix it without rebooting.

[image: Cursor messed up]

When I take a screenshot from gimp it shows up ok:

[image: normal cursor from gimp screenshot]

I'm using 64-bit Xubuntu 14.04 and my graphics card is a Radeon HD 6670/7670 according to lspci.  I'm using the fglrx driver. Another weird thing is that it only shows up this way on one of the screens (I think screen 2 in radeon settings). Its fine on the other screen.

---

Comment: You could try [this guide](http://ubuntuguide.net/stop-restart-x-window-in-ubuntu-12-04), but it does Log you out (at least, it did for me) so that might not help you. You could also try another driver (if available) if the issue persists after reboots.

Comment: Rebooting fixed the issue.

Comment: Could you please add your response as an answer (instead of a comment) and mark it as the correct answer, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This works for me when Ubuntu Mate 14.10 corrupts my mouse cursor. It doesn't require a restart.

```
Ctrl+Alt+F2
Ctrl+Alt+F7
```

I always get this bug when dragging an image with Eye of Mate image viewer, and a TTY switch makes it go away. Restarting also works, but changing the cursor in the appearance settings does not.

Comment: Thanks. That's usually one of the first things I try to see if it fixes an X problem. I'd be surprised if I didn't try it when this came up. I'll try if it comes up again.

Comment: What does this combination do?

Comment: @CadentOrange Ctrl+Alt+F2 then Ctrl+Alt+F7 switches to a virtual console that doesn't use X11, then back to the virtual console that uses X11 (http://askubuntu.com/questions/277517/what-does-ctrl-alt-f12-do). Since X11 is responsible for drawing your graphical environment including your mouse, switching from and then back to the X11 console may cause your mouse cursor to be re-buffered in a non-corrupted state.

Comment: You are great, man!