# Import ics file?

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, korganizer

I received an `.ics` file that is a reminder for a Calendar Software.

I know some Microsoft applications can open it but I found no Linux programs that can open it.

I tried to import it in `KOrganizer`, but it would not open that file extension.

This did not work for me.

We can open an .ics file directly using Evolution, KOrganizer or Calendar. But it is sad that Ubuntu default mail client is unable to add the .ics directly to the calendar system.

Comment: I have no idea what the file is; but I'd look at it and see if I could recognize it. First let the system try, eg. `file whatever.ics` which will tell you what the system see's it as (using contents of file and not its name). Then I'd look myself `hexdump -C whatever.ics |less` (or use cat|zcat etc as appropriate given what 'file' reported the contents as being..)   This is more a 'while you wait' for others that know what the file contains..

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate -- if you don't use Thunderbird as your email client, opening `.ics` files in Lighting is a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open an `.ics` file with [Calendar](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Calendar) or [California](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/California).

There is [talk](https://github.com/pimutils/khal/issues/111) of implementing such a feature in [Khal](https://github.com/pimutils/khal/), but it doesn't look like anything has come of that yet.

If you care ... I run both because Calfornia has a better interface but it has been abandoned, and only `Gnome-calendar` actually syncs with my cal dav server.

Comment: California froze up my system. I can't even open a terminal to run Htop in order to kill it.

Comment: ouch! If you didn't already restart, ctrl-alt-F2 should get you to a virtual console, where you can log in and kill California. Use `ps aux | grep california' to find the pid. (You'll need ctrl-alt-F7 get back to X11) -- more on that at https://askubuntu.com/questions/277517/what-does-ctrl-alt-f12-do#277539

Comment: I was able to log out. I will keep your tip in mind.