# Ubuntu 19.10 , What causes a login loop error?

Tags: nvidia, login, 19.10

Let me put you in context, you see this is the third time I install ubuntu on my laptop (Asus Laptop, running NVDIA GTX 1050), althought this installation was different because I once for all removed the original Windows 10 that came with my Laptop.

My first attempts were on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and were in a dual booting manner yet I did not had a great time, you see I ran into the login-loop problem twice!, some fellas of mine told me that the reason of it might have been because Ubuntu 18.04 was not the kindest with NVDIA graphics card, anyways I never knew exactly how did I got involved with the login loop problem and I never solved it even tho I did try many posible solutions.

6 months has passed since the last attempts and yesterday in my insanity I installed Ubuntu 19.10 for good throwing Windows away, since I heard that Ubuntu 19.10 fixed the problems with NVDIA graphics and so far I have no problems with it, Im actually happy and amazed, it runs so smoothly.

But deep inside im scared of the login loop curse that i have, does any of you guys know how to PREVENT the login loop from happening, what causes the login loop?

Comment: How do you know the question is simple? What if there are many possible reasons? How many do you want?

Comment: You are right, I do not know, I just want to know what caused it or what might caused them? Any information is useful

Comment: I can think of a dozen typical causes for the display server or desktop environment to crash, resulting in a "login loop". Each possible cause has, of course, it's own range of possible fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most common things that can cause a login loop is the use of `sudo` to start a graphic application... like:

`sudo gedit filename`

The way to prevent this is to use `sudo -H`... like:

`sudo -H gedit filename`.

See `man sudo` for more details about `-H`.

And because of this, what can happen is that these two files get changed to `root` ownership... and you get a login loop.

ls -al .*authority

```
-rw------- 1 username username 451352 Nov  2 13:34 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 username username     58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

Then you would have to boot into Recovery Mode, and manually set the file ownership back to the proper username using the `sudo chown` command.

**Update #1:**

Instead of booting into Recovery Mode, an alternate way is you can simply go to another virtual console (e.g., Ctrl+Alt+F2 to go to tty2), log in there, run `ls -l` to see what files are affected, and then run whatever `sudo chown` ... command is appropriate.

Comment: There's no need to boot into recovery mode to fix this, because it doesn't affect non-graphical logins. One can simply go to another virtual console (e.g., Ctrl+Alt+F2 to go to tty2), log in there, run `ls -l` to see what files are affected, and then run whatever `sudo chown ...` command is appropriate.

Comment: @EliahKagan thanks for the additional info. Are virtual consoles available at the login screen? I'll have to try that sometime when I have some kind of trouble. I'll add your quote in my answer.

Comment: Yes. [Virtual consoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) are provided by the kernel. The GUI, if running, will be on one of them, in the sense that switching to it shows the GUI and switching away hides it. This works both at the greeter (login screen provided by a display manager) and while logged in to a desktop session. Switching *from* a GUI to the *n*th virtual console (tty*n*) requires Ctrl+Alt+F*n*; otherwise, Alt+F*n* is enough. [Usually not all virtual consoles have a terminal with a login prompt on them, but the first 6 or so usually do.](https://askubuntu.com/q/277517)

Answer (score -1):

Changing the file /etc/fstab if you dont know exactly what you are doing would give you the login loop, if you're looking for causes, but I think you are more into preventing the login loop at all, and I think you can never know for sure. Don't be discouraged tho there is a way to avoid it and that is everytime you're going to touch some config file or system file, `cp` the file into a `file.old` and that way if you get the login loop you just have to press `Ctrl+Alt+F3` in the login screen and revert the change you did using the shell.

Comment: What do you mean by system files, you mean does files that are outside of my `/home/myusername` folder. that being the case I should be carefull when I run commands like apt-upgrade or apt-install right ?

Comment: Well `apt-upgrade` and `apt-install` wont hurt a thing, editing files outside your `/home/username` that is what I mean. Just be careful when using `rm` and `nano`/`gedit` on files.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thank you!.

Comment: I don't see how editing /etc/fstab can cause a login loop.

Comment: @BenjaminGil I'm not sure I'd buy this.

Comment: Well it was the only reason I've gotten login loop so far. I was trying to mount my `lvm` partition and got something wrong in the `dump` and `pass` syntax that caused the login loop, it was a nooby mistake but as new ubuntu user i though it was pretty common. I think if you read carefully the rest of my answer I gave an useful answer for a new user which is basically to make backups of files before editing giving a way to revert the changes in case he gets the login loop.