# Stuck on black screen with blinking cursor and mouse pointer after I force closed during upgrade

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade, kernel, partial-upgrade

I ran `sudo apt upgrade`. The process got stuck at 49% and my laptop hanged. I couldn't do anything at all to make it work, so I force closed like I used to do in Windows. Now when I boot it up, it sticks on a black screen with a blinking cursor and mouse pointer.
How to fix it?

**Some background**

Also, my laptop is **Acer Aspire 7** (Ryzen 5000 series), so it has some problems with **kernels 5.10** lower. So I had updated the LTS version default kernel to the latest one. If that was in any way the reason for this issue.

Also, I did not use the new 21 version because I wanted to run ROS2 and its support is till 20.04 only for now.

Comment: I would start going to [a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F4)](https://askubuntu.com/q/277517/349837) and `sudo apt install --fix-broken && sudo update-grub`

Comment: @PabloBianchi When I enter my username and password then after that terminal initial msg this thing comes Terminal error https://imgur.com/gallery/dIiy4A2

Comment: You can't reach the shell? Already rebooted? Seems a nouveau issue, did you try `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`? Do you have enough space? `df -h`