# Disable keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+F11 (Gnome?)

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156712/what-does-ctrl-alt-f11-do-and-why-cant-i-log-into-my-account-with-unity-any) situation where pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> brings up a blank screen with a flashing cursor.

I can't see where to disable that key combination. Any help? From the link above it seems to be a Gnome thing.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but to go back to your graphical session, keep pressing Alt+left for a while.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+F1 helped on my Ubuntu 22.04. I was astonished that this happened to me, I was trying to set a keymap in IDEA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires some manual X11 server configuration. Look in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`; if it doesn't exist, you'll need to create it (type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a Terminal and run `sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` on it) with the following contents:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
  Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
EndSection
```

If it does exist, look for a Section `"ServerFlags"` and add the `Option` line above to it; if there isn't one, append the above lines to the file.

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/302460/how-to-disable-ctrl-alt-function-key-combinations-on-debian)

Comment: Source: http://superuser.com/questions/302460/how-to-disable-ctrl-alt-function-key-combinations-on-debian