# GUI frozen on restart after using Ctrl+Alt+F11

Tags: login, kde, plasma

What happend:
I was checking what `Ctrl+Alt+F11` does while setting up macros, then entire laptop froze, I've tried to click(spam) it again and nothing happend so I've restarted my laptop

After restart instead of login screen I see boot up background, Mouse is visible and movable

How to fix that?

Tried:

- `Ctrl+Alt+F7 / F8` - makes my mouse dissapear and nothing else
- `Ctrl+Alt+F11` then `Ctrl+Alt+F7` - same as above
- Waiting 15 minutes in frozen screen

Ubuntu distro: KDE Neon

Plasma Version: 5.27

(I will send console output later if needed)

There was similiar question asked before:

[What does Ctrl + Alt + F11 do and why can't I log into my account with Unity any more?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156712/what-does-ctrl-alt-f11-do-and-why-cant-i-log-into-my-account-with-unity-any) But for them GUI froze after logging in for me it freezes before showing log in screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a /home folder on second disk and it turns out that the entire disk broke somehow probably when I forced restart on my laptop. (Which is why login screen was not working)

I bought a new disk and reinstalled the system. If anyone else has the same problem I recommend checking is everything ok with home folder on the bootable usb.

I know this is a reallyy late answer but maybe it will be useful for somebody

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl +alt+f7 worked for me.

The screen had gone black while doing ctrl+alt+f11 (fulls screen browser)